# How to handle tinyMCE content in CodeIgniter 3

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, tinymce-4, codeigniter-3

I have added tinyMCE editor in my app which is developed in CodeIgniter 3. But I am having issue in handling it's content on POST.

When content is submitted, and if any other field has error, so it needs to show the content which user submitted, but that it is showing tags.

Initially it looks like this:

[image]

And afr submit it looks like this:
[image]

How to fix this so that even multiple POST submits it looks properly, nit with tags?

Comment: looks like `htmlentities()` has been used on the data. Try decoding it

Comment: @charlietfl No, htmlentities is not used anywhere.

Comment: Not much information given. Haven't shown what the actual string is or how it gets passed to editor. Editor also has a source view that's not shown. In order for that image to appear like that htmlentities (or similar) had to be used somewhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your own extension of form helper with next function within:

```
function set_ta_value($field, $tv = NULL)
{
    $CI =& get_instance();
    if ($CI->input->post($field)) return $CI->input->post($field);
    return $tv;
}
```

`set_ta_value()` should be used instead `set_value()` for text area field.
[Docs](http://forum.codeigniter.com/thread-1035.html).

All credits go to @Wouter60.

Comment: `set_value` is have a third parameter in CI 3, making that `false` fixed that.

Comment: I saw that, but in topic I linked, didn't seem it was solution. All in all, good if you solved problem. Happy coding. :)